# ASP.NET 4.6, Identity Framework and SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-identity

I have an **ASP 4.6 MVC Website** (All updated to the latest Nuget Packages) which uses the integrated Identity Framework with Entity Framework on SQL Server.

If I use the *Connectionstring* with my Database Administrator everything works find, but when I switch to an extra Databaseuser I get an "Login failed for user...".

I created the User in the Master Database with this:

```
CREATE LOGIN user1 with password='geheim'
```

And then added him to the Database with this:

```
CREATE USER user1 FROM LOGIN user1 

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'user1' 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'user1'
```

I can connect with this credentials from *SQL Enterprise Manager* to *SQL Azure* and query my Database, but cannot use Identity on the database.

Any ideas which roles or rights are needed to use the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long debugging Sessions i found the solution:
The Identity Framework ties to scan the Database if the throwIfV1Schema is set to true.
As i use a custom IdentityDbContext i had to change the constructor to this:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(Settings.DSN, False)
End Sub
```

Now the Startup of the Identity Framework only needs a User for the current Database.

Comment: In Addition to this the App-Startup can be very slow (>30 sec) on Azure AebApps if you did not add the User to the master Database.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making the LOGIN name different from the USER name. You can find detailed instructions on how to set this up and what roles to use at the following link: [SQL Database security: Manage database access and login security](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/)

The following example is provided from that page which is similar to what you have.

```
-- first, connect to the master database
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';
CREATE USER login1User FROM LOGIN login1;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'login1User';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'loginmanager', 'login1User';
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work.
I can only connect to the Database with Entity Framework AND Entity Framework if i use the SQL Azure Database Admin.
Any other Users (with Server Users -> Database Users and the new V12 contained database users) does not work.

Comment: See my comment. The User must be also in the master database to speed up app Startup.